# Sync two SQL Server databases on different networks?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server running on company network, which contains data that's treated as source of truth. The application is hosted outside this network and is using a different SQL Server. Currently I manually transfer data using some combination of node & SQL scripts, from the company SQL server DB to the application DB.

I'd like to automate this manual process. Real-time update is **not** necessary.
Should I create a web app/service that can be run to start and finish the copy process? Or does SQL Server (or SSMS) provide some better solutions?

Please note that, I will also have to perform some kind of modification to the data before I insert in my application DB (like adding a column of certain JSON value, for example). So it's not just a straightforward backup.

Comment: Can't this column be generated on the target site? If it's calculated from whatever else in the source db

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Service Broker will be the most interesting functionality to do that...

It's a SODA architecture (Service Oriented Database Architecture) where service from a SQL Server instance communicates data with another service on another SQL Server instance over the https layer by internal MS SQL "web" services...

The dialogue on data is transactional, serializable, cyphered, and you have the guarantee the data has been delivery.

[Just read the MS learn about that feature...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker?view=sql-server-ver16)